# What graphic programs are used in Wind-up knight

Tags: 3d

What graphics programs does Android support?  i.e. what graphics programs did Robot Invader use to create Wind-up Knight?

Any hints or clues are appreciated.

Comment: What technology some particular game used is defined as [off topic](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) for the site. Beyond that there are plenty of 3D engines, if that's what you mean by "graphics programs". Android uses [OpenGL](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html).

Comment: Hi David, welcome to the Game Dev Stack Exchange! As Byte56 already mentioned, this particular type of question is considered off topic for our site. Please do [check out our FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) which specifically mentions this type of question as an example of a bad question (among other reasons, it is too specific). You might seek the answer to this question elsewhere, such as contacting the developers of "Wind-up Knight", or consulting the Android Developers guide on [Graphics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

See http://robotinvader.com/blog/ - developers blog.  I see they mention Unity.